# aspectj-maven-plugin compilanceLevel for java 10

Tags: java, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I've been trying to to compile a project that relies on aspectJ-maven-plugin it works fine with the compilanceLevel 1.9(java 9) but when it comes to java 10 apparently it is not supported?

```
ERROR]  Compliance options:
[ERROR]     -1.3               use 1.3 compliance (-source 1.3 -target 1.1)
[ERROR]     -1.4             + use 1.4 compliance (-source 1.3 -target 1.2)
[ERROR]     -1.5 -5 -5.0       use 1.5 compliance (-source 1.5 -target 1.5)
[ERROR]     -1.6 -6 -6.0       use 1.6 compliance (-source 1.6 -target 1.6)
[ERROR]     -1.7 -7 -7.0       use 1.7 compliance (-source 1.7 -target 1.7)
[ERROR]     -1.8 -8 -8.0       use 1.8 compliance (-source 1.8 -target 1.8)
[ERROR]     -1.9 -9 -9.0       use 1.9 compliance (-source 1.9 -target 1.9)
[ERROR]     -source <version>  set source level: 1.3 to 1.9 (or 6, 6.0, etc)
[ERROR]     -target <version>  set classfile target: 1.1 to 1.9 (or 6, 6.0, etc)
```

its there anyway to workaround this?

Comment: Where is your code? What is your concrete problem?  What does not compile under Java 10 with language level 9? Why do you need  language level 10?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this problem too. Since the ajc documentation is laughably out of date, I *finally* found the problem in the source code. For Java 10, you cannot use 1.10 for the compliance level, source, and target. You must use 10.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- MUST use 10, NOT 1.10 or ajc breaks -->
        <complianceLevel>10</complianceLevel>
        <source>10</source>
        <target>10</target>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: The new documentation is present here - https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#complianceLevel

Comment: I have a similar issue with 1.8 and this actually let me build using Maven. I did not get this error using IntelliJ.